# New to Pi 3 and hardware -Connecting Pi 3 to a sensor

Tags: pi-3, sensor, ds18b20

I bought the following items:

1. Raspberri pi 3:
   [image]
2. Breadboard:

[image]

3. Jumper wires:

[image]

4. Temperature sensor DS18B20:

[image]

5. 4.7k resistors:

[image]

My question - I never learned electronic or hardware and I'm simply trying to follow tutorials how to connect between all those things and can't figure out.

My primray goal is to view the temperature in my room using my Pi.

My question:
**How I can connect the sensor to my Pi using my equipments?**

I can't find any way to wire the jumper wire from the breadboard to the sensor and the Pi. There is no place I can connect a jumper wire in the Pi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your cables are "male" at both ends (pin sticking out), and the GPIO pins on the Pi are male also (those 2 rows of 20 pins). You have 2 options:

1. Get jumper wires that are male at one end (that's what you need for the breadboard) and female (gap for a pin) at the other end (that's what you need for the Pi. Keep your male-male wires, that's what you need to connect things between themselves on the breadboard, you'll just need a few male-female wires to connect parts of the breadboard to the GPIO's of the Pi.
2. Get a female-female header for the Pi so you can use your male jumper wires.

Answer (score 0):

You need to buy some male-female jumper wires.  The male end will plug into the breadboard.  The female end will plug into the Pi and the sensor.  I'd buy some female-female jumpers at the same time, they will likely be useful in the future.